# Peut-on dire "J'ai fait beaucoup hier"?

Tags: grammaire, usage, adverbes

En anglais on peut dire

> I did a lot yesterday.

Peut-on dire l'équivalent en français:

> J'ai fait beaucoup hier.

ou

> J'ai beaucoup fait hier.

ou doit-on dire plutôt

> J'ai fait beaucoup de choses hier.

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we strictly take your original stentence,

> J'ai fait beaucoup de choses hier.

is the most idiomatic option in conversational French (at least for a French or Belgian speaker).

*J'ai fait beaucoup* and *J'ai beaucoup fait* without specifying a lot *of what* are more often used with a preposition of purpose or manner, not time.

> J'ai beaucoup fait pour la cause.
>
> On peut faire beaucoup avec de l'aide.

Alternatively, you can use ***en** faire beaucoup* to emphasize the effort it took, though it would be quite a stretch from your original question.

> J'en ai fait beaucoup pendant deux semaines, mais maintenant je me
> repose.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the three sentences are syntactically good and have the same signification.

"J'ai beaucoup fait pour t'aider hier" 
"J'ai fait beaucoup hier pour t'aider"
"J'ai fait beaucoup de choses hier pour t'aider"

**Are all correct** but the two first one sound a bit more unfamiliar and are closer to formal language. And the exact translation of "J'ai fait beaucoup de choses hier" is "I did a lot of things yesterday".
They all have the same meaning, you worked hard for something or someone.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

In normal conversation: I did a lot yesterday.

J'ai fait plein de choses hier.